# Is vampirism genetic?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I found someone that I think might be a vampire, but he's married and has a young child. His wife is somewhat suspicious too. I'm thinking of just executing the three of them. Can a vampire marry a non-vampire? Would their child be vampire?

Comment: This is an oddly interesting question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No, it is not**, because vampires are supposed to be sterile. (Note however that it has been reported this feature isn't working right.) So if your putative vampire has a wife and kid, *and they both acknowledge him as the father*, either he isn't really a vampire, or it's from his previous life as a mortal. Note that mutual agreement about relationships is important. Vampires will falsely claim to have relatives, even spouses and children, in distant lands, even if no such dwarves exist; only relatives also at the fortress are safe.

In any case, the wife and child are probably perfectly normal dwarves, unless they have independently become vampires themselves (which is vanishingly rare). Vampirism cannot be transmitted genetically for the simple reason that vampires cannot have children (barring bugs as above). In this case, since the child is young, I would probably guess that the father isn't actually a vampire; what has he done that inspires you to think he is?

Note however than executing the father will cause an impressive bad thought for his wife and child. If you're not prepared to handle this, and they're new immigrants so they don't have other friends in the fortress, you might as well execute all three.

Comment: Do you know if they still marry if they're vampires?

Comment: I believe that they do not, but not very strongly. So if you've heard that they do from a reliable source, I'm happy to be wrong on this point.

Comment: Just an FYI: Vampires will lie about having children.

Comment: Yup, that's right in my first paragraph. Any claim about relatives not at the fortress is subject to suspicion. If a someone claims another fortress inhabitant as his child, you can check the child's relationships to see if she agrees (which she probably won't if he's a vampire). But if he claims his kid is far away, you can't doublecheck, so you can't trust him.

Answer (score 2):

[vampires themselves are sterile](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=101181.msg3035405#msg3035405), but the guy might have contracted vampirehood after getting the child